# how can i display astronauts sorted from most to least time in space on javascript

Tags: javascript

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "active": false,
      "firstName": "Mae",
      "lastName": "Jemison",
      "skills": [
            "Physician", "Chemical Engineer"
      ],
      "hoursInSpace": 190,
      "picture": "mae-jemison.jpg"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "active": false,
      "firstName": "Frederick",
      "lastName": "Gregory",
      "skills": [
            "Information Systems", "Shuttle Pilot", "Fighter Pilot", "Helicopter Pilot", "Colonel USAF"
      ],
      "hoursInSpace": 455,
      "picture": "frederick-gregory.jpg"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "active": false,
      "firstName": "Ellen",
      "lastName": "Ochoa",
      "skills": [
            "Physics", "Electrical Engineer"
      ],
      "hoursInSpace": 979,
      "picture": "ellen-ochoa.jpg"
   },
]

i have no 
idea
```

Comment: `astronauts.sort((a, b) => b.hoursInSpace - a.hoursInSpace);`